# validar una variable en jquery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy usando `jquery.validate` y tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un campo de imagen, que cuando la imagen no existe lo relleno con una `img` por defecto... pero necesito que ese campo sea requerido y no es una opción tener la imagen por defecto guardada en `bd`. Necesito algo como esto:

```
 $('#idForm).validate({
     rules:{
         name:{
             required:true
         },
         photo:{
             required:imgNew?true:false
         }
     }
 })
```

O sea lo que quiero que me valide es si la variable tiene valor y no si el campo tiene un valor.
el campo `img` tiene lo siguiente:

```
<img ng-src="{{imgSrc ? imgSrc : '/images/no-image.jpg'}}" data-  toggle="modal" data-target="#avatar-modal">
```

En ese modal hay un input tipo file que es el que le da valor a la variable `imgSrc`. Lo que necesito es que ponga el cartel como lo hace `jquery.validate` cuando variable sea null o este vacia. Saludos

Comment: por que no subes mas código sobre la problemática, esto nos ayudaría a buscar la solución. Por otra parte, cuando dices: Tengo un campo de imagen, te estas refiriendo a que tienes un input donde colocas la url/nombre de la imagen?.

Comment: realmente es un campo <img> que tiene como src por defecto una imagen para que no se vea vacio, cuando se da click en el levanta un modal que tiene un input tipo file que ahi es donde se carga la imagen, cuando esta tiene valor se sustituye el src por defecto por la imagen

Comment: Yo opino que falta más código... agrega tu código.... para así darle directamente al punto

Comment: codigo agregado, espero que baste con eso para dar idea de lo que necesito

Answer (score 1):

El validate solo te sirve para mandar mensajes de que ese campo es requerido en caso de que no contenga informacion, la pregunta aqui es como es tu campo imagen? Este se carga por defecto, este cambia al hacer click en algun lugar o como? En todo caso lo que debes hacer es usar la opcion de ".val()" para obtener el valor de ese campo este es un ejemplo:

```
var img = $('#IdImagenInput').val();
if (img != "") { //img == "undefined" img != "undefined"... etc 
   var tieneFoto = true/false.. etc
   tus metodos aqui....
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder... el problema es que yo en el src del campo de imagen cargo una imagen por defecto para conservar el estilo y eso no se vea feo, por tanto cuando le pongo al campo required:true,esta valido, porque tiene un elemento... pero realmente no hay imagen... por eso el src real de la imagen lo tengo en otra variable, que cuando existe sustituye esa imagen por defecto

Comment: Ese campo como cambia? Al cargar una imagen mediante un boton o algo? En ese caso lo que puedes hacer es esto, declaras una variable que sea igual a la ruta que pones por defecto y en el if que te puse solo agregas if (img != laVariableConElSRCPorDefecto)

Comment: ok, miguel, lo que quiero que sepas que el problema no esta en validar la variable, el problema esta en que muestre el cartel como si no estuviera valido como lo hace jquery.validate

Comment: Nada de eso decia tu pregunta... en fin, lo que se me ocurre es que pongas un label oculto y mediante la misma funcion de $('#TuId').val verifiques si el valor que tiene es el correcto y si no que le quites el atributo oculto al label y ya sea visible, es esto algo como lo que buscas?

Comment: si, exactamente eso es lo que hace jquery.validate, intercepta el submit del formulario y valida si esos campos son correctos, pero como estoy haciendolo con jquery.validate, seria super si pudiera validarlo dentro de el, como si fuera una regla o algo asi.

Comment: En mi opinion creo que esto no es posible. Te hice un ejemplo a ver si esto te sirve: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LREoJN